# Notes regarding Real analysis

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I recently came across professor [Alan Sokal page](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahad0/) , which contains beautiful handout notes for functional analysis. These notes are very helpful to work with functional analysis. The interesting and challenging fact is to fill the gaps in these notes.  Especially Sokal asks "Why" in most of the lines in the proof of every theorems and filling these details is very interesting. Now I want these type of notes in Real analysis.  I already found [COMPANION NOTES: A Working Excursion to Accompany BabyRudin](https://bomongiaitich.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/silvia-em-companion-to-rudins-principles-of-analysis-web-draft-1999434s_mcet_.pdf) by Evelyn M. Silvia  in online and this notes has also an interesting gaps to work.

Is there any other such type of notes ? Any suggessions ?